# hot reload overlay with avconv

Tags: libav

I use avconv to encode a rtmp stream.

I have a PNG overlay over the video.

I would like to, each time the png picture is updated, the overlay is updated to.

Si I try to add:

`-f image2 -loop 1 -i /score.png`

but I still have to restart the stream to refresh the overlay picture

```
avconv -f video4linux2 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 -f image2 -loop 1 -i /score.png -filter_complex "overlay=20:160" -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/
```

`avconv` options are the same than `ffmpeg` ? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735121/ffmpeg-continuously-stream-refreshing-image-to-rtmp)

Ideas ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I installed `ffmpeg`, `image2` works fine with ffmpeg